# publish_actions permission in facebook sdk for python

Tags: python, django, facebook, api, sdk

I am working on app in django 1.11 with facebook-sdk (v. 2.12 for facebook).

I have problem with added permissions to publish content on wall. I got an error:

```
(#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission
```

Below is my code:

settings.py

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '###########'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '############'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_API_VERSION = '2.12'
```

code in view.py

```
from social_django.models import UserSocialAuth
import facebook

facebook_login = UserSocialAuth.objects.get(provider='facebook')
oauth_token = facebook_login.extra_data["access_token"]
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(oauth_token, version="2.12")
profile = graph.get_object(facebook_login.extra_data['id'])
graph.put_object(parent_object='me', connection_name='feed', message='Hello, world - test :)')
```

I got an error in last line:

```
graph.put_object(parent_object='me', connection_name='feed', message='Hello, world - test :)')
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the token has the `publish_actions` permissions?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24